# When I check the email and the password of an user I cant load other scene if the credentials are the corrects

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I have a script who Sing up with a mail and a password and i have an "if" who check if the email and the password are correct. I'm using FirebaseAuth in Unity 2022.

My script is this.

```
public void Init()
    {
       
       FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;

       auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(mail, password).ContinueWith(task => {

            if (task.IsCompleted && !task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.Log("Login successful!");  // Log successful login
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Principal"); 
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Login failed: " + task.Exception);  // Log failed login
            }
       });
       


    }
```

The problem is that when I put the email and the password (there are correct) the section [Debug.Log("Login successful!")] works, but [SceneManager.LoadScene("Principal")] doesnt. And in the unity console there arent any error, so it seems that this line did not exist.